# Socket Error 11001 when calling function in another module from main

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a script `scanner.py` that receives data from a socket connection and writes it to a text file. It works on its own, but I wanted to package it with another script into one application using Pyinstaller.

For this, I created a `Main.py` that reads a config file for host address and port number and then calls the function in my `scanner.py`

Scanner.py:

```
def server_connect(host, port):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
            s.connect((host, port))
            while True:
                data = s.recv(1024)
                """do something"""
```

Main.py:

```
from scanner import *
import configparser
import os
import threading

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_file(open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"setup.ini")))

host_1 = config['Host']['host_1']
host_2 = config['Host']['host_2']
port = int(config['Port']['port'])

scanner_1 = threading.Thread(target = server_connect, args = (host_1, port))
scanner_2 = threading.Thread(target = server_connect, args = (host_2, port))

scanner_1.start()
scanner_2.start()
scanner_1.join()
scanner_2.join()
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
line 7, in server_connect
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

When I just try printing the variables in my scanner.py, I get the values correctly:

```
def server_connect(host, port):
    print(host,port)
```

So it does not seem to be a problem of not passing the variable values to the function correctly. It also works if I pass the host address and port here in `Main.py` directly `scanner_1 = threading.Thread(target = server_connect, args = ("192.168.51.29", 51236))` . What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated!

Update: Added a snippet of my `setup.ini`

```
[Host]
host_1 = "192.168.51.29"
host_2 = "192.158.51.30"

[Port]
port = 51236
```

Comment: Could you show the output of `print((host, port))` when the connect fails?

Comment: @MarkTolonen `('"192.168.51.29"', 51236)` ahh! I see what is causing that error, those extra single quotes. But where do these come from?

Comment: Provide your `setup.ini`...or at least the portion that makes your code above return the incorrect value.  Make a [mcve].

Comment: Take the quotes out of the `setup.ini` file 

Comment: Fixed the problem by removing the double-quotes from `host_1` and `host_2` values in the `setup.ini`. Configparser wraps the values in quotes even if it is already a string, didn't know that was a thing. Thank you Mark!